# Remove or reduce noise from a recorded audio using FFMPEG

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Is it possible to remove/reduce noise from an already recorded audio file (.mp3/.wav) using FFMPEG?

What is the command?

Comment: For audio processing, rather than FFMPEG try [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: See also [this similar thread on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/733061/reduce-background-noise-and-optimize-the-speech-from-an-audio-clip-using-ffmpeg).

Answer (score 5):

A bit late, but if anyone finds this helpful, I wrote a simple script to do exactly that (it reduces noise from both audio and video files), find it here: https://github.com/yonilevy/noiseclean

Comment: the end result introduces some new noise, kind of sounds like watery or beeping. but it did help remove the noise from a crappy video I had.

Answer (score 0):

Directly with FFMPEG is not possible, because it is only encoder/converter of various audio/video formats, you need third party tool like Audacity (http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Release_Notes_2.0.0), which is free or Adobe Audition, which is paid.

Comment: Is possible to use from my PHP program or from linux shell like ffmpeg?coz we record the video from using my php program , i want to remove noise from the recorded video

Comment: This is incorrect, it is possible to apply filters in ffmpeg that does this. See https://superuser.com/questions/733061/reduce-background-noise-and-optimize-the-speech-from-an-audio-clip-using-ffmpeg